# How do I check if Geb Module "content" is present?

Tags: geb

I'm a bit new to the whole `Selenium`/`Geb` thing, so I'm probably going about this a bit wrong, but I'm trying to get the `exists()` method in the following code to work properly.

```
class Question extends Module {
    static base = { $("fieldset") }
    static content = {
        input { $("input[type=text]") }
        name { input.getAttribute("name").toString() }
    }
    boolean exists() {
        return input.isPresent()
    }
```

Frustratingly, when I try to execute that code (from a Spock Test, "go"ing to a PageObjectm including this module, I get the following:

> The required page content 'input - SimplePageContent (owner: question - Question (owner: MyPage, args: [], value: null), args: [], value: null)' is not present

I've tried a number of other things, including:

- `if (input) return true; return false`,
- `... input.size() == 0`,
- Using `static at = {...}` (doesn't seem to be supported for modules"

Any ideas

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default Geb ensures that your content definitions return non empty elements. If your content is optional you can tell it using [`required` content option](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/pages.html#required):

```
name(required: false) { input.getAttribute("name").toString() }
```

Because Geb utilizes Groovy Truth to redefine how navigator are coerced to boolean values(empty navigators are falsey and non-empty are truthy) you can simplify your `exists` method to:

```
boolean exists() {
    input
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your response. I'll give it another go, but not sure why your answer would be different than my `if (input) return true; return false,` (not how the code *actually* looks) attempt. I'll try again shortly.

Comment: The `exist()` implementation is indeed just a cosmetic change, but you need to set `required` to false on the content definition so that you won't get the exception about missing required content.

Comment: Hmm... maybe. Still haven't gotten a chance to tinker with it again today, but I *do* know (and shouldv'e stated) that the exception occurs on the line I execute the `exists()` method

Comment: And I explained what to do to get rid of it - use `requried` content option.

Comment: I know. Sorry, was just making sure we were on the same page. I'll take a look at this again today...

Comment: Hah! It works! Sorry I was perhaps a bit reluctant to trust that this answer was in fact correct without testing. I (thought I) tried stuff that was very similar to your answer, but I guess I was off somehow. This is verified as working now, thanks for your help!